# How to get product_options for sales_order_item by API Rest?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, bundle-product

How to get product_options for sales_order_item ? I need the price of simple product (bundle)

[image]

Comment: with a SQL query or programmatically ?

Comment: How can you get option value using API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `quote_item_option` table :

```
option_id, code, item_id, product_id, value
```

Comment: Tks. Its possible to get this information by API Rest?

Comment: not sure, check this one `/V1/carts/:cartId/items`  or see : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html#quote